# Finger capture in React-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, camera, fingerprint

I came across an app and wanted to implement the same in **React-native** but I couldn't find any library which gives me this feature Or any other way to implement it.

I want to capture a single-finger picture.

Is there any library in React-Native?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you want to capture fingerprints you can use [`react-native-fingerprint-scanner`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fingerprint-scanner), or there are several React Native libraries that you can use to pass biometric security of OS, it won't give you the fingerprint data. it just uses a Native API of OS to just compare fingerprint to saved on and tell you it is passed or not.

If you considered, gathering fingerprints data from users by using biometrics, it's not possible. but you can use it another way. use camera, you know, I was studying artificial intelligence in my Master degree, I used palmprints for my project.

Or gather data from some universities or institutes like RIKEN studio.

Comment: Appreciated.But what i need is to compare the fingerprints with the fingerprints in database.
This usecase is not applicable to my project